# Load and return data with AJAX to use later

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I am trying to write a simple function to load an array from XML in javascript. I have successfully been able to send the AJAX result to a function using the `success:` field when calling `$.ajax(...)`.

Also, I've noticed that the return value of the function `$.ajax(...)` is an `Object`, which has fields `responseText` and `responseXML` (which I would be happy to use). However, even though I can see them in the tree on my console, trying to access them via `.responseText` does not work (and so prints `undefined`, the same if I were to try looking up some junk string `.this_does_not_exist`).

I am going to do this nearly identically with several different XML files, I'd like to do it with code. The reason I'm not content to simply have the `success:` parameter kick the results to a separate function is because I may use the data multiple times, but only want to load it once. I'm trying to separate loading and using the XML so that it isn't loaded several times.

Can you tell me why `responseText` shows up when I output `xml_ret`, but is not accessible by `xml_ret.responseText`?

Thanks a lot for your help and patience.

---

**Note:** to load `test.xml` from the same directory, you need to launch Chrome or Chromium this way:

```
chromium-browser --allow-file-access-from-files
```

**test.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function print_XML(xml)
      {
      console.log( "in printXML" );
      console.log(xml);

      $(xml).find("point").each(function()
      {
      var loaded_row = [ parseInt($(this).attr("number_protein_groups")), parseInt( $(this).attr("log_likelihood") ) ];
      console.log( loaded_row );
      });
      }

      function load_and_print_XML(fname)
      {
    console.log( "in load_and_print_XML" );

      xml_ret = $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: fname,
      dataType: "xml",
      success: print_XML
       });

    console.log( "xml_ret" );
    console.log( xml_ret );
    console.log( xml_ret.responseText );
      }

    </script>

</head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      xml_data = load_and_print_XML("test.xml");
      /* do something with xml_data here */
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<results>
  <replicate_result graph_filename="yeast_1.pivdo">
    <point number_protein_groups="10" log_likelihood="20"/>
    <point number_protein_groups="20" log_likelihood="40"/>
    <point number_protein_groups="40" log_likelihood="60"/>
    <point number_protein_groups="50" log_likelihood="50"/>
    <point number_protein_groups="60" log_likelihood="55"/>
  </replicate_result>
</results>
```

**My console:**

```
in load_and_print_XML
test.html:30xml_ret
test.html:31
Object
abort: function (a){a=a||"abort",p&&p.abort(a),w(0,a);return this}
always: function (){i.done.apply(i,arguments).fail.apply(i,arguments);return this}
complete: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
done: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
error: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
fail: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
getAllResponseHeaders: function (){return s===2?n:null}
getResponseHeader: function (a){var c;if(s===2){if(!o){o={};while(c=bG.exec(n))o[c[1].toLowerCase()]=c[2]}c=o[a.toLowerCase()]}return c===b?null:c}
isRejected: function (){return!!i}
isResolved: function (){return!!i}
overrideMimeType: function (a){s||(d.mimeType=a);return this}
pipe: function (a,b,c){return f.Deferred(function(d){f.each({done:[a,"resolve"],fail:[b,"reject"],progress:[c,"notify"]},function(a,b){var c=b[0],e=b[1],g;f.isFunction(c)?i[a](function(){g=c.apply(this,arguments),g&&f.isFunction(g.promise)?g.promise().then(d.resolve,d.reject,d.notify):d[e+"With"](this===i?d:this,[g])}):i[a](d[e])})}).promise()}
progress: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
promise: function (a){if(a==null)a=h;else for(var b in h)a[b]=h[b];return a}
readyState: 4
responseText: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>↵<results>↵  <replicate_result graph_filename="yeast_1.pivdo">↵    <point number_protein_groups="10" log_likelihood="20"/>↵    <point number_protein_groups="20" log_likelihood="40"/>↵    <point number_protein_groups="40" log_likelihood="60"/>↵    <point number_protein_groups="50" log_likelihood="50"/>↵    <point number_protein_groups="60" log_likelihood="55"/>↵  </replicate_result>↵</results>"
responseXML: Document
setRequestHeader: function (a,b){if(!s){var c=a.toLowerCase();a=m[c]=m[c]||a,l[a]=b}return this}
state: function (){return e}
status: 200
statusCode: function (a){if(a){var b;if(s<2)for(b in a)j[b]=[j[b],a[b]];else b=a[v.status],v.then(b,b)}return this}
statusText: "success"
success: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;n(arguments),j?l=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(k=a,o(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
then: function (a,b,c){i.done(a).fail(b).progress(c);return this}
__proto__: Object
test.html:32undefined
test.html:9in printXML
test.html:10
Document
<results>​
<replicate_result graph_filename=​"yeast_1.pivdo">​…​</replicate_result>​
</results>​
test.html:15[10, 20]
test.html:15[20, 40]
test.html:15[40, 60]
test.html:15[50, 50]
test.html:15[60, 55]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the question:

> Can you tell me why responseText shows up when I output xml_ret, but is not accessible by 
>   xml_ret.responseText?

It's happening because when you do console.log of an object, for example in chrome, that keeps the reference to the object in the console. If the object changes, those changes are reflected by chrome's console.

So what's happening is that when you do:

```
console.log( "xml_ret" );
console.log( xml_ret );
console.log( xml_ret.responseText );
```

the ajax request haven't finished and the responseText still haven't been assigned, that's why it appears as undefined. However the xml_ret object printed is a reference to an object so when the ajax request finishes if you go to check the values on the console it has a "responseText" property because it has already been set.

You can see that if you debug the code and add a breakpoint in this line:

```
console.log( xml_ret.responseText );
```

When looking at the file xml_ret it doesn't have the "responseText" property.

PS: I'll need to review this comment for sure. Too late too think :P

Comment: Thanks!

Actually to be annoying it seems like chrome's console evaluates the object when you try to access it's properties. 

If you debug and try to see xml_ret properties before the ajax request is finished responseText doesn't appear and that won't change later. However if the first time you try to access the properties is after the ajax request is finished it shows the responseText.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I changed the ajax parameters to `async: false` and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the console will update object's if they get updated but not string's.

So if you call an ajax call the function will directly return an object but `responseText` will be undefined because the call isn't completed yet.

So if you want to use the `responseText` you should do it on success:

```
function print_XML(xml, s, jqXHR) { // there are 3 arguments past the third one is the same as the return of $.ajax
    console.log( "in printXML" );
    console.log(xml);

    $(xml).find("point").each(function()
    {
    var loaded_row = [ parseInt($(this).attr("number_protein_groups")), parseInt( $(this).attr("log_likelihood") ) ];
    console.log( loaded_row );
    });

    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText); // now it works!
}​
```

Comment: This might be useful to him later, but the problem he needs help with is the weird behaviour with xml_ret.responseText.

Comment: micha, my comment was added before your edit, when you were just talking about parsing the response.  Your updated text is more on topic, and I agree that processing it in the success call is correct, but I'm not sure it's just a timing issue, because `console.log(xml_ret)` does output the correct values *before* it fails to do so on `xml_ret.responseText`.

Comment: Ah, after reading user433831's answer I see what you were getting at.  +1 to both of you; you explained it first, but I think the other answer was clearer.

Comment: @ElYobo yes you're right user433831 explained it much better. When I was writing the answer before I've missed to look at the code above that's why it was off topic.

Answer (score 0):

responseText  shows up when you output xml_ret because that's how the ajax function works in jQuery. This is what gets returned in the callback

success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)

So when you are trying to grab a property of xml_ret it fails because it is just the XML data and not an object. The third argument is what you expected, also it is slightly modified as it is a jquery one.

Comment: That's not true; as per the documentation, the jqXHR object is returned from the AJAX call - you can see this in the debug output which he has included above.

Comment: Ah yeah my bad, at the top of the doc too, damn I should go to bed :)